# How to replace variables with matrices form rather than as lists form?

Tags: matrix

According to an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#2%C3%972_matrices) of Cayley–Hamilton theorem,

```
m = {{1, 2},{3, 4}};
mc = m~CharacteristicPolynomial~λ
```

Output:
$\lambda ^2-5 \lambda -2$

---

```
mc /. λ -> m // MatrixForm
```

Output:
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -6 & -8 \\
 -8 & -6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$     (This is obviously *wrong*.)

```
-2 IdentityMatrix@2 - 5 m + m.m // MatrixForm
```

Output:
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$     (This is the *correct* result, but how to perform with `Replace` etc.?)

Comment: As you're probably aware, `Power` is not the same as `MatrixPower`, and `-2` is not the same as `-2 IdentityMatrix[2]`. You can get some of the way there with `-2 - 5 λ + λ^2 /. {λ -> m, Power -> MatrixPower}`, but I don't have a clean way to deal with `-2`.

Comment: `Expand[im mc] /. {Power -> MatrixPower, λ -> m,   im -> IdentityMatrix[2]}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IdentityMatrix[2] (mc /. {Power -> MatrixPower, λ -> m})
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

or

```
im mc /. {Power -> MatrixPower, λ -> m, im -> IdentityMatrix[2]}
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for [`MatrixPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html):

> An easy way to evaluate a matrix polynomial:
>
> ```
> mpe[p_, x_, m_] := Module[{cl = CoefficientList[p, x]},
>   Sum[MatrixPower[m, i - 1] cl[[i]], {i, Length[cl]}]]
>
> mpe[1 + 2 x + 3 x^3, x, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
>
> (*  {{114, 166}, {249, 363}}  *)
> ```

The problem that follows this one in the docs is to evaluate the characteristic polynomial on a matrix, which we apply below to the OP's example:

```
mpe[mc, λ, m]
(*  {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MatrixFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixFunction):

```
MatrixFunction[
    Function[λ, Evaluate[mc]],
    m
] //Simplify
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Comment: Thanks. But this way (0.013542s) is significantly slower 290 times than that of @kglr's answer (0.000046s).